# how to set background image for scroll area with out affecting other widgets in pyqt5?

Tags: python, css, pyqt5

I tried to set QScrollArea background image. it is affecting other widgets like line edit and label too. how to set image only for scroll area background. I added code below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import os,sys

class SDK(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        GL=QGridLayout(self.widget)

        for i in range(10):
            L=QLineEdit('text_'+str(i))
            GL.addWidget(L,i,0)
            LE=QLineEdit()
            GL.addWidget(LE,i,1)

stylesheet2="""QScrollArea QWidget {border-image: url("D:/1.jpg") 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet2)
    window=SDK()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got answer for my issue, by assigning

```
self.widget.setObjectName("home")
```

and assign stylesheet

```
stylesheet2="""#home , #setting{border-image: url("D:/1.jpg") 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}"""
```

[image]